# how can i make user assign look stacked?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

> I want each user to be stacked, neat as in the picture how can i make user assign look stacked? i want like this :
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIU6v.png)

> my result now :
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5i3j.png)
>
> my code :

```
          Row(
            children: List.generate(3, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'asset/img/profile_photo.png',
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make widgets stack on top of another, you need to use the `Stack` widget.

```
Stack(
  children: List.generate(3, (index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: (index * 0.5) * 40), // distance from the left
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        child: Image.asset(
          'asset/img/profile_photo.png',
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i usually do stacked widgets like that. try it out

```html
Stack(
           clipBehavior: Clip.none, 
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < yourList.length; i++)
                  Container(
                  
                //* you can adjust the margin here base on your desired output
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12 * i.toDouble()),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'asset/img/profile_photo.png',
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ]),
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it makes the distance even further @john

Comment: you have to adjust the margin based on your widget size

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit the row to `Stack`, i edited and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to use `Stack` to make everything looks stacked, not `Row`. You can use something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const WIDTH = 80.0;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
            children: List.generate(7, (index) {
          return Positioned(
            left: (WIDTH - 30) * index,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0*index),
              ),
              width: WIDTH,
              height: 40.0,
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            ),
          );
        })),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Result: [image]

Remember to calculate distance carefully. I use `Positioned` and calculate **`left distance = (WIDTH - 30) * index`**. It is kinda same as your images, just adjust few things, then OK. Good luck!